# Logic App : Gmail Connector Send Email From email not showing Name

Tags: gmail, azure-logic-apps

I am using Logic App : Gmail Connector. When I am sending email through Gmail mailbox, At the receiving mailbox, I am seeing the name of the sender along with email Id. But when I am sending email through Logic App Gmail Connector, I can only see the email Id and not name.

[image]

Comment: I have the same question. Were you able to figure out any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

***I have reproduced in my environment, It is default template of gmail connector in logic app that you will be only able to see only the sender email . The sender mail id will always be the email id which you have logged in(i.e., the credentials you've used for connector:***

[image]

[image]

***Output:***

[image]